# Splash screen: showing delayed and different than preview

Tags: android, splash-screen

I've implement a simple splash screen layout, with an image and with a circular progressbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SplashActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/mysplash" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        layout="@layout/progress_bar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now i have two problems. 
My drawable resource for ImageView it's a big squared (3000X3000) image for fit all screens that have a background and a logo in the middle.

First problem:
Android studio preview show splash layout as i expect, but when i launch app, i can see only a portion of splash image on top left corner of screen

Second problem:
I have a delay between when Activity is launched and splash image (with previous described problems) appear.

How can i fix it?

Comment: The main problem is the mysplash image is too huge. Use can use Glide to load this image. The splash screen will slow display only for the first time.

Comment: Use an image loading library, there is a problem with your image, it's probably too large.

Comment: ok, i've make image half resolution, now it loads well.